# EasyRDF example not working for me on server

Tags: php, rdf, easyrdf

I'm setting up easyrdf for a project so I'm trying the homepage example. Locally all is fine. However as soon as I change the file different to the example one (`http://njh.me/foaf.rdf`) or doing the same example code w/ same graph but on a server, It's not working anymore. I use composer to install easyrdf.

The example is:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$foaf = new EasyRdf\Graph("http://njh.me/foaf.rdf");
$foaf->load();
$me = $foaf->primaryTopic();
echo "My name is: ".$me->get('foaf:name')."\n";

?>
```

I get Class 'EasyRdf\Graph' not found (0). Whats the cause of it not working on the server?

Comment: I suspect that you are experiencing two different problems. "Class 'EasyRdf\Graph' not found" sounds like a problem with the autoloader or missing files. How did you install EasyRdf on your server? Did you just upload the files from you development machine, or did you run composer on the server?

Comment: @njh I've used Putty to access server and run composer on the directory of the project. Just in case I've "composer update"ed it before replying to you, nothing changed. It's the easiest example to setup, that's why I'm puzzled why it's not working.

Comment: @njh with some help I've managed to make the example work on server, however it still works only with `http://njh.me/foaf.rdf` graph. Using the same rdf but from a different url (`https://oziz.ffos.hr/nastava20192020/bungar_19/p3ont/foaf.rdf`) gives a 500 error (`Call to a member function get() on null (0)`). Is it because of HTTPS? It's the same RDF...

Comment: Can you also post the stack trace, which usually contains the line which causes the error? Your initial post seems answered though, but the new error is kind of odd. Can you try with the latest 1.0.0?

Comment: @k00ni It was quite odd that such simple example wasn't working. It might have something to do with rdf file and it's contents, as I changed all references to njh.me inside it and it worked. Or it was something besides easyrdf in vendor that cause problems, added some suggested packages. Had no problems with my own rdf neither later on. I'm not nearly knowledgeable enough with this field to be certain what was the cause or answer, but my specific situation has been solved

Comment: Hi @BornaUngar, good to know. Can you add `but my specific situation has been solved` to your question so that others also see that? Without further information like a stack trace I am not sure what else we can do here.